# Releasing connections from connection pool

Tags: java, connection, connection-pooling

In our code (which runs as a schedule job via timer), we have threads running in parallel to perform a database operation. Problem here is each thread is initiating a connection via Hibernate factory. These connections are closed after every database action but stil gets stocked in the connection pool(as INACTIVE). All the connections gets released only after the job/main process is killed.Is there any way to release the connection even from connection pool after the database operation. When we use cron job instead of timer, the process gets killed automatically but we dont need cron here. 
Kindly help us to resolve this as we are already nearing production release. 
**Note : We came to know about this when QA tested with heavy load on the job and for each load new connections are pulled.**

Comment: sounds like a connection leak and not a pool.

Comment: We suspected the same. But we have went through the code and we have made sure we have closed all the connections. What happens is when we close the connection, it goes back to the pool rather than releasing and the pool gets freed only when the mail thread is killed. So can we get the pool released without actually exiting the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to restrict the number of threads getting created in the thread pool.

dotConnect for Oracle uses connection pooling. The OracleConnection connection string has the Pooling parameter. If Pooling=true (the default value), the connection is not deleted after closing it, it is placed to the pool instead. When a new connection with the same connection string is opened, it is taken from the pool (if there are free connections) instead of the creating a new one. This provides significant performance improvements. If you use 800 connections that are connected for 10-15 seconds each, and there are only few different connection strings, you may not have 800 actual connections. Closed connections will be placed to the pool, and they will be taken from the pool when a new connection with the same connection string will open. No additional connection will open in such case.

You can disable Pooling by adding 'Pooling=false' to the connection string. In such case, a connection will be deleted from memory and free the session. However this may lead to performance loss.

Most likely, pooling should not cause creating too much sessions. Try testing your application with pooling on. If the session number will be too large, you can disable pooling.

For more information, please refer to http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/FAQ.html#q54

Comment: We cant do that as it is existing legacy design, People dont wanna change anything now. Any other suggestions? Like interrupting the thread or killing the thread will release the connection from pool ? when does the pool connections gets released?

Comment: Thread can never be killed or stopped. You need to restrict the number of threads you create. So other option is to close the connection when the job is done which you are already doing it. Which DB are you using? Check the document if you can restrict number of connections that can be created at db side can be controlled

Comment: We are using oracle 11g. yes we can restrict the same via thread pool size and other parameter. another problem here is the session factory is initiated everytime the database call is made and not made as singleton for generic use across application. Also if I restrict, the threads have to wait for other threads to release the connection. So kind of hit a dead lock without knowing how to release pool connections. Any option to manually release pool connections?

Comment: Please refer the answer

Comment: Thanks @bhuvan . Never tried with concept of pooling as false. As of my knowledge, oracle implements default pooling if we have no specified anything. let me try with the pooling as false as we have heavy load. Will keep posted.!! Thanks a lot !

Comment: disabled the pool settings and now we are able to save some considerable amount of connections .... Can see connection count in v$session is reduced to greater amount in this case... Thanks a lot for the suggestion!! :)

Comment: oops!!!! missed a major log...! It has thrown error on closed connection for statement execution!!

Comment: Bhuvan .. got that fixed.. it was a silly mistake.. I found an intermediate solution. I reduced the min and max connection and also the timeout for releasing the connection from pool to 1 ..... This helped me to get the connections in a stable number.

Now we have refracted code at some places to use shared session factory .... this has considerably reduced the connection count!! Thanks a lot for your suggestions ... we are yet to test it fully.... :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the root cause for the issue and have also found the solution.
The root cause was number of connections set as minimum and maximum and the time out parameter.
The minimum was 5 and max was 20 and timeout was 800 seconds. But out job was scheduled to run every minute. Due to the configuration, the connections were not released properly within minute.
Another issue was our code was not using the session factory as singleton, but was initializing for each thread. Since the resource was not shared, each session factory creates 5 connections by default and extended to 20 max. Since the timeout also was higher before the connections are released, next set of job starts and creates its own set of new connections. 
Finally the pool gets full and oracle becomes unavailable.

We fixed this by sharing the session object across and also setting the timeout to lesser value so that connections are getting released from pool.